# Custom directive data unable to pass to method in Vue 3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

In my html I reference the directive: `v-init:url="myurlhere"`

```
    data() {
      return {
        currentPage: 1,
        url: '',
        news: '',
      }
    },
    directives: {
        init: {
            mounted(el, binding) {
                console.log(binding.value);
                this.iterateUrlContents(binding.value)
            },
        }
    },
    methods: {
        iterateUrlContents(url) {
            console.log('url: ' + url);
```

`console.log(binding.value)` shows the expected result, however when I call iterateUrlContents I get the following:

> Unhandled error during execution of directive hook
>
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'iterateUrlContents' of
> undefined

And I also find that if I try `this.url = binding.value` I get

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'url' of undefined

Why is binding.value undefined, and how can I pass this information to my method?

Comment: You're trying to access a function that's not in-scope for the directive.
The directive doesn't have access to the function iterateUrlContens (it's part of the component, not the directive).
You could create a function *outside* the component scope and use that.
like
`const iterateUrl = () => {} // your function

export default {
  name: 'MyComponent',
  directive: {
   mounted() {
    iterateUrl(url)   
}
 }
}`

Comment: btw I should mention that using it this way would be more preferable than using the component instance from the directive, especially if you cannot guarantee that the directive is exlusively used on components and not on basic DOM elements.
Composition API would encourage you to create pure functions that you can simply import wherever you need it.

Comment: Thanks @Braks I have that working. Yes my next step is getting that value into the component methods now.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access the component instance you need to do it via `binding.instance` in Vue3.

Comment: Thanks Stephan. Can you provide me some context/elaborate on this please? Thank you